# How can I set a rectangle as background for ImageViews and buttons?

Tags: android, imageview

I am new to Android app development. I want to draw a rectangle and set it as background for an ImageView and buttons. I have already created an XML file inside the drawable folder which creates the rectangle but how can I use it as a background for the ImageView and the buttons?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
                android:background="@drawable/your_rectangle_xml_file"
```

Comment: Please consider to mark it as correct if it was what you needed.

Comment: I want the ImageView and the buttons to have the same rectangle as background. Is it feasible?

Comment: Yes, just add your rectangle xml as background in all your imageviews and buttons. If it doesn't work post your code and i will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a rectangle.xml in drawable folder and paste the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#000000"></solid>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/_5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/_5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/_5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/_5dp"
    ></corners>
 </shape>
```

after that in your activity use it as like

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your text" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="your image "
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

create shame.xml in drawable

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
   android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

and in youractivity.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Shap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Shape"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```